# Enviando imagem do android para um servidor node js

Tags: android, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e preciso que ele registre uma foto, e envie para um servidor que esta rodando node.
Nesse mesmo projeto já esta funcionando uma troca de dados através do socket.io e agora preciso enviar uma imagem.

Não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma ideia a se seguir é converter a imagem em base64 e enviá-la no formato de texto, depois desconverte no lado do servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, você teria algum exemplo codificado de como eu possa estar fazendo isso?